# how can print data form multiple table in rails association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

i have created project, stage, task and sub_task scaffold. project has one to many association with stage, stage has one to many association with task and task has one to many association with sub task. i want to render each task's all sub_task in project#show, currently i am able to render all sub_tasks to each task.

routes.rb

```
  resources :projects do
    resources :stages do
      resources :tasks do
        resources :sub_tasks
      end
    end
  end
```

projects_controller.rb

```
  def show
    @project = Project.includes(stages: :tasks).find(params[:id])
    @stages = @project.stages
    @sub_tasks = SubTask.all
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include the `subtasks` along with `tasks` as follows:

```
 def show
    @project = Project.includes({stages: {tasks: :sub_tasks}}).find(params[:id])
    @stages = @project.stages
    # Now when you iterate through stages, you can fetch tasks associated with each stage, and for each task, you can get subtasks. All of this happens without additional DB queries because of the "includes"
  end
```

This would fetch all stages related to a project, all tasks related to each stage, and then sub tasks related to each task!

Comment: Isn't that what you want though? As mentioned in the question "i want to render each task's all sub_task in project#show". Could you please explain what the expected out is?

Comment: I've updated the answer. I had left `@subtasks = SubTask.all` in it by mistake

Comment: Yes, with the updated answer, you'll have to make a few changes to your view as well. I believe up till now, you were using the @sub_tasks variable to show subtasks, which would've fetched all sub tasks. Could you please make suitable changes or add your erb code as well to the question?

Comment: i got it. Thanks!!

Comment: "All of this happens without additional DB queries because of the 'includes'" is somewhat missleading. `includes` fetches the whole assocation once for all the members of the collection in seperate db query - includes tries to be smart though and does not do this until the assocation is first referenced. If you want to load the assocation up front use `.eager_load` instead.